# How to disable package hooks for update-initramfs?

Tags: initramfs

I am trying to build a minimal initramfs.

Some packages contribute hooks that don't appear to take any config option to enable/disable them. For example `initramfs-tools-core` provides a `fsck` hook and `fuse` provides a `fuse` hook.

Is there an intended way to exclude these when running `update-initramfs`?
Simply deleting the hooks (e.g. `rm /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse`) would work, but they'll come back when installing updates.